# Saving zip files in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, zip

I am aware you cant save files in a document database which MongoDB is. However as a work around I am trying to convert the zipped folder into bytes which i can then convert back to zip format when fetching the data from the database later. To process the data and communicate with the database I am using python. For the sake of testing I am saving the byte data in a txt file instead of uploading to the database.

I have tried a lot of different methods but this is my current base code:

```
# path to zip folder used for testing 
zipLink = "/Users/XXX/Desktop/XXX.zip"
# path for the txt file to be created 
testTxt = "/Users/XXX/Desktop/test.txt"

# read zip folder in binary mode 
with open(zipLink, 'rb') as file_data:
    bytes_content = file_data.read() 

# write bytes into txt file as string
# meant to simulate upload to database 
with open(testTxt, 'w') as file_data:
    file_data.write(str(bytes_content,'utf-8'))

# read bytes from txt file as string
# meant to simulate fetch from database 
with open(testTxt, 'r') as file_data:
    stringData = file_data.read()

# create a new zip folder using the bytes read from the text file
with open("/Users/XXX/Desktop/Remade.zip", 'wb') as file_data:
    file_data.write(bytes(stringData,'utf-8'))
```

I know the problem is with the encoding because when i skip the steps of the txt file and converting the bytes into a string, I am able to recreate the zip folder from the bytes.

The errors I keep getting are like the following:
"UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xab in position 11: invalid start byte"

I have tried different encodings and tried using different python libraries to figure out the encoding of the string read from the txt file. All throw a similar error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use UTF-8 encoding for binary files.

In Unicode encodings like UTF-8 or UTF-16 you have many Bit combinations which are not allowed. Just for comparison, Unicode has an address range of 32 Bit, i.e. 4.3 Billion addresses, however Unicode defines only 1,114,112 Code-Points. So, the wast majority of all possible Bit combinations are not allowed.

Usually when you need to convert a binary file into text, then you use [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). Most languages have built in functions for that, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html

As long as the string is not longer than 16 MiByte, it is no problem to store them in MongoDB. Otherwise you have to use [GridFS](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/core/gridfs/)

Answer (score 0):

The following works and it uses base64 but I will be looking into GridFS for future cases:

```
import base64

# path to zip folder used for testing 
zipLink = "/Users/XXX/Desktop/XXX.zip"
# path for the txt file to be created 
testTxt = "/Users/XXX/Desktop/test.txt"

# Reading zip file as binary and converting it to utf-8 which can be stored as a string 
with open(zipLink, 'rb') as file_data:
    bytes_content = file_data.read() 
    base64_encoded_data = base64.b64encode(bytes_content)
    base64_message = base64_encoded_data.decode('utf-8')

# Saving string to text file simulating saving it to database 
with open(testTxt, 'w') as file_data:
    file_data.write(base64_message)

# Reading string from text file simulating fetching it from database 
with open(testTxt, 'r') as file_data:
    stringData = file_data.read()

# converting it back to binary format 
base64_bytes = stringData.encode('utf-8')
decoded_data = base64.decodebytes(base64_bytes)

# recreating the zip file from binary data 
with open("/Users/XXX/Desktop/Remade.zip", 'wb') as file_data:
    file_data.write(decoded_data)
```

Comment: No idea why do you encode the data as UTF-8. A Base64 string is pure ASCII, which is compatible with UTF-8. Thus it should not change anything.

Comment: If you remove both lines with "utf-8", then you get the following error "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes". Thats because "b64encoder()" returns bytes not a string. If you only remove the "encode(utf-8)" line then you get the following error "TypeError: expected bytes-like object, not str" with this "  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/base64.py", line 510, in _input_type_check
    m = memoryview(s)
TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"

Comment: Ah, ok. In this case it does not matter which encoding you use, because almost all encodings in this world are a strict superset of ASCII.